how to check if the parameter of one agent is equal to the parameter of another agent in AnyLogic?
I have a simple model with two agents, Shipment and Location. The Shipment has different parameters including "destination". The Location is a population of agents with a parameter called "name" which is the name of each location and another parameter called "shpNbr".

The shipments start from source, go to the queue and then delay block. In delay block, I want to check the shipment's destination and if it is equal to one of the name parameters in location, it increases the shpNbr parameter for that location by one.
I appreciate it if someone could help me with that. I do not know how to refer to the parameters of different agents in the Main window and compare them.

for (Location l: locations){
if (l.name.contains(agent.destination))
    l.shpNbr++;}


First, understand your model hierarchy, this is extremely important as every model is different: https://anylogic.help/advanced/code/access.html#where-am-i-and-how-do-i-get-to
If (and only if) you have a Shipment agent embedded in Main and a Location agent embedded in Main, and if the flow chart itself is on Main (!), you can use code in your Delay block similar to
agent.whateverStringParam.equals(myLocationAgent.whateverOtherParam)

this returns true or false, use that in an if-statement or however else.
If it still does not make sense, I recommend a "Java for AnyLogic course" as this is very important to grasp

Thank you so much for your time, Benjamin.I appreciate it. After running the code, I get the following error:" MyLocationAgent cannot be resolved to a variable"

it is pseudo-code, you have to adjust to your actual model. Never type code, always use code-complete. myLocationAgent was my way of saying "put your location agent name here". See https://anylogic.help/anylogic/ui/using-intelli-sense.html

Thank you so much for the clarification , Benjamin. I changed my agent name as you said but it did not still work. The code that I copied in the answer worked though.

didn't say to change your agent name but to adjust the pseudo-code to your model :) Glad you got it working, always use code-complete :)
